# AngularJS- catch $q.reject in promise.then block

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angularjs app, i am trying to catch the $q.reject in one of the promise block and unable to do so.

In below code i have rejected the response if the response returns empty data and i need to catch that rejected response in one of the promise block and do some redirection using $state.
Currently it is not going into the error block from success block on $q.reject().

Is there a way to catch the $q.reject into promise block??

```
    x.retrieve=function(id){
         return $http.get(url);
    }


  var promise=x.retrieve(id);
  promise.then(
       function(response){
        if($.isEmptyObject(response.data)){
           return $q.reject(response);
        }
       y.push({x:a});
     },function (rejection) {
       $state.go("detail");
     }
 );
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What is `$q` here? is it a newly created defered object? What does your method return.. Can you show more code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing it in this format instead.

```
promise.then(function(response){
  if($.isEmptyObject(response.data)){
    return $q.reject(response);
  }
  y.push({x:a});
}).catch(function (rejection) {
  $state.go("detail");
});
```

**UPDATE**: 
for IE you can do it like this:

```
promise.then(function(response){
  if($.isEmptyObject(response.data)){
    return $q.reject(response);
  }
  y.push({x:a});
})['catch'](function (rejection) {
  $state.go("detail");
});
```